# CUDA performance with respect to threads per block

Tags: cuda

I am experimenting with CUDA for interests. In one of the experiment I had a small kernel which was only running in for loop for 10million times. I send 1 block and then increased the number of threads per block from 1-1024. Then I plotted the execution to see how it varies. The results is that there is sharp rise at around 350 thread per block and then there are sharp rise at gradual moments. The execution time becomes 2x at 1024 thread per block indicating that atleast one thread has been blocked. The actual graph is like an increasing ladder. What I want to understand is why and on what number these rise depend. I am trying to understand it wrt to number of SM,cuda cores etc.

I am using GeForce 560 Ti with  8SM, 48cores per SM and 2 warp scheduler per SM.

Answer (score 2):

One possible reason for sharpe rise at 350 threads per block is that the block consumes too much resources so that a SM cannot process more than one block at a time.  You can use CUDA Occupancy Calculator see how many blocks will be handled by one SM at a time based on the resource usage of your kernel.

Comment: I was also going to answer this with a pointer to the CUDA Occupancy Calculator. It will show those "stair" type graphs that you see. It also shows all the factors that go into determining the occupancy for a given kernel and lets you play around with the numbers to see how everything interacts.

Comment: However I want to know one thing - since I have 8 SM with 48cores ch then this implies I can run 8x48 threads concurrently then what is meant by 1536 active threads per SM. I expect that if I have 23 threads per block and I increase the blocks then I should get a jump at 16 blocks since each block uses 23 cores hence 2 block can come in 1 SM so total 16 concurrent block. I found no jump at 16 but at 64 which is the limit of maximum concurrent blocks

Comment: It comes down to definitions. What does "running" and "active" mean? The 32 cores in a CC 2.0 device means that you have a potential throughput of 32 single precision floating point / integer / logical operations per clock. Similar for the 16 load/store units and the 4 special function units. But the cores are pipelined, so there is a long latency. So at each clock, one set of threads adds their calculation to the pipeline, one set of threads receive their results, and lots of theads are on hold, waiting for their results to come through.